# How to avoid hardcoding sliding window duration in Drools and pass time-window as argument.

Tags: drools, drools-guvnor, drools-fusion

I have started using drools a week ago.
I need to calculate average of a metric over a window-duration, say 4s. Below code-snippet of Drools will do this job.

```
...  over window:time(4s) ...
```

However, I want to take this value as input to a rule with the value taken from control-panel UI where someone, say the customer, can specify the window duration.

I tried many options, including the one below, but that doesn't compile.

```
...   over window:time($SlidingWindowDuration)
```

Googled for hours, but there is little documentation available on this subject.

Any clues in this regard would be of great help to me.

Answer (score 0):

The length of a sliding window:time cannot be set dynamically. (I think this is so because dynamic lengths would make it impossible to infer an expiration offset for the automatic removal of obsolete events.)

Note that if this length can be set by the user *before* the engine is started and remains constant afterwards, you can insert the duration into the rule text, compile on the fly (only the rules that need last-minute editing) and execute.

To be absolutely dynamic, you'll have to implement the "window" mechanism explicitly. Make the timestamp an attribute of the event and set it explicitly: then you can base reasoning on timestamp differences, retract old events explicitly and compute the average over all that's left using a simple accumulate CE.